# Deploying .NET Core Application with Windows Compatibility Pack

Tags: deployment, .net-core, event-log

I'm busy deploying a .NET Core 2.1 application into our testing environment, but I'm getting the following error.

```
Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (MyApp.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'System.Diagnostics.EventLog', version: '4.5.0'
    path: 'runtimes/win/lib/netcoreapp2.1/System.Diagnostics.EventLog.dll'
```

We are using the [Windows Compatibility Pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility/) to access the Event Log.

I have the following item in the dependency Json file:

```
"System.Diagnostics.EventLog/4.5.0": {
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.Win32.Registry": "4.5.0",
    "System.Security.Permissions": "4.5.0",
    "System.Security.Principal.Windows": "4.5.0",
    "System.Threading.AccessControl": "4.5.0"
  },
  "runtime": {
    "lib/netstandard2.0/System.Diagnostics.EventLog.dll": {
      "assemblyVersion": "4.0.0.0",
      "fileVersion": "4.6.26515.6"
    }
  },
  "runtimeTargets": {
    "runtimes/win/lib/netcoreapp2.0/System.Diagnostics.EventLog.dll": {
      "rid": "win",
      "assetType": "runtime",
      "assemblyVersion": "4.0.0.0",
      "fileVersion": "4.6.26515.6"
    }
  }
}
```

Please advise how one should deploy these dependencies. Also, what is the root folder to this relative path `runtimes/win/lib/netcoreapp2.0`?

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @matthid Not for this specific solution no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We actually found a solution for our scenario:
- Our situation was that we tried to run a netcoreapp based test project on our test agent
- `dotnet test` on the project file worked
- `dotnet vstest` sometimes worked on the project output directory (we are not sure why and on  which setup)
- `dotnet vstest` did run into the above error when run into an other directory & downloaded from CI
- `dotnet vstest` did run into an `AssemblyNotFoundException` on the test agent (which didn't make any sense for us)

The solution was to use `dotnet publish` for our test project and use the "self-contained" output to run on the test agent. `dotnet publish` copied the required `runtimes/win/lib/netcoreappX.X/*.dll` files into the publish output directory.

Comment: Thanks for sharing.

Comment: this worked, but shouldn't it mean that the .NET runtime is not installed? I know I have .NET Core 3.1 installed, but it looks for files in a netstandard2.0 path... (.NET Core 3.1 is supposed to be an implementation of .NET Standard 2.0). I see the dlls in the root of the publish folder, which is why this works, but why can't it find those dlls from the .NET Core runtime installation?

Comment: Ok, I think the difference might be that I am compiling an x86 project but on the target system I have only .NET Core 3.1 x64 installed.

Comment: I tried removing the x64 .NET Core App 3.1 and that did not help. I can see that even in a normal build, the right dlls are present so I don't know what the difference is.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of testing, the key issue seems to be the "RuntimeIdentifiers". There is a visible option for this when you publish, but in order to use it when just building you need to add a couple of tags to your .csproj file.

The first is:

```xml
<RuntimeIdentifier>win-x86</RuntimeIdentifier>
```

This will cause NuGet to retrieve the correct dlls (change the value depending on your needs). For me I was compiling to platform x86. I don't know what NuGet was getting by default, but whatever it was had different file sizes for the same files.

You also should then add this tag:

```xml
<SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
```

or else your build will default to copying the entire framework.

Also note that using the `RuntimeIdentifier` tag will cause your default output folder to include the value you specified. For example my subfolder became:

```xml
Project\bin\x86\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\win-86\
```

For publishing you should be able to do something similar; the problem will be to match your RuntimeIdentifier to your platform. You shouldn't need to specify SelfContained unless you specifically need to.